# How to update LiveData value?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-paging

I am using the new paging library for my data. Everything works fine when the ViewModel is created and live data is first initialized. Problem is that I can not update the value of my live data when for example I click on menu Item and want to update it with a different set of data. Then onChanged method in my fragment does not get called. I have read about MutableLiveData and methods like setValue and postValue which can update the live data, but in my case, I am using LivePagedListProvider and cannot return MutableLiveData from a database.

Dao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM teams ORDER BY name ASC")
LivePagedListProvider<Integer, Team> getAllTeams();
```

Fragment:

```
mTeamViewModel.mTeamsList.observe(this, new Observer<PagedList<Team>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable PagedList<Team> teams) {
            mTeamAdapter.setList(teams);
        }
});
```

ViewModel:

```
public LiveData<PagedList<Team>> mTeamsList;

@Inject
DatabaseManager mDatabaseManager;

void setTeamViewModel(final DatabaseManager databaseManager) {
    mDatabaseManager = databaseManager;

    mTeamsList = mDatabaseManager.getAllTeams().create(
            0,
            new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                    .setPageSize(50)
                    .setPrefetchDistance(50)
                    .setEnablePlaceholders(true)
                    .build());

}

boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_favorite:
            mTeamsList = mDatabaseManager.getFavoriteTeams().create(
                    0,
                    new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                            .setPageSize(50)
                            .setPrefetchDistance(50)
                            .build());
            return true;
        default: return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Update annotated method will do a trick (or Insert or Delete)

Comment: Do you mean to update, insert or delete something in my table so it will trigger onChanged ? That might work, but what should I update ?

Comment: you should update the record you want to change, but for learning purposes just insert new record - it is a lot easier

Comment: ok, but i do not want to change anything in my table, i just want to get different set of data, like in my example get just "favorite" teams and then update my adapter with it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally I found the solution after the struggle of 3 days,

For updating the value of `LiveData<PagedList>` we can use `MediatorLiveData`, as follows, inside your `ViewModel` class:

```
public LiveData<PagedList<RecipeListPojo>> liveData;
private MediatorLiveData<PagedList<RecipeListPojo>> mediatorLiveData;

public RecipeListViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    mediatorLiveData = new MediatorLiveData<>();
}

public MediatorLiveData<PagedList<RecipeListPojo>> init(RecipeDao recipeDao, RecipeFrom recipeFrom, String orderBy) {
    liveData = new LivePagedListBuilder(recipeDao.getAllRecipesList(simpleSQLiteQuery), 6).build();
    
    mediatorLiveData.addSource(liveData, new Observer<PagedList<RecipeListPojo>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable PagedList<RecipeListPojo> recipeListPojos) {
                mediatorLiveData.setValue(recipeListPojos);
            }
        });
    return mediatorLiveData;
}
```

Further details can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData) about MediatorLiveData

Comment: Have you tried DataSource.Factory in konjunction with MediatorLiveData ? Did you succeed ?

Answer (score 2):

Create a `isFavourite` column in your model. Then:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM teams WHERE isFavourite = true")
LivePagedListProvider<Integer, Team> getFavouriteTeams();
```

Then you should have a `ViewModel` with a function/field that returns a `MutableLiveData<PagedList<Team>>` and in the `Fragment`/`Activity` you observe to that field. In your `Fragment`/`Activity` you tell the `ViewModel` every change you need to do to de list showed. Then in the `ViewModel` you assign different values to the live data list.

Comment: But I do not want to show just two lists. In fact, I have 5 different options to show a list based on category. So I think that to create an adapter for each of them is not the best option. Instead what works for me is using just different observers, but one adapter. What also works is removing and setting one observer everytime I click on one of my categories. Do you think that this approach is good ?

Answer (score 1):

Transformations.switchMap can help: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations#switchmap

```
class SearchViewModel() : ViewModel(){

val teamId = MutableLiveData<Int>()

var teamsList: LiveData<PagedList<Team>>=
    Transformations.switchMap(teamId) { id ->
        //just example
        if (id <= 0) {
            //1
            searchDbManager.searchWithoutId()
        } else {
            //2
            anotherSearchDbManager.searchWithId(id)
        }.setBoundaryCallback(SearchResultBoundaryCallback()).build()
    }
}

fun changeTeamId(id : Int){
   teamId.postValue(id)
}
```

If you want to change the search process to search with team ID (or switch to another datasource), just call from Fragment:

```
viewModel.changeTeamId(2)
```